# how to exclude resources from being copied within Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I'm doing a build intellij, I get errors due to emacs creating temporary files that are not able to be packaged

```
Error:Maven Resources Compiler: Failed to copy '... /.#env_app.clj'
```

Is there any way to exclude the `.#` files from intellij?

Comment: Does it work from command line Maven? In IDE, the compiler excludes are configured in Settings(Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | *Excludes*. But for Maven projects compiler excludes (as other build-related options) must be configured via pom.xml files.

Comment: yes. adding `<exclude>**/.#*</exclude>` does work. If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IDE, the compiler excludes are configured in Settings(Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | **Excludes** settings page.

But if it is a Maven-based project, the compiler excludes (as other build-related options) must be configured via pom.xml files:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/.#*</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```